# Error: Property 'getConnection' does not exist on type 'Bluebird<Pool>'

Tags: javascript, mysql, ecmascript-6

I need help, trying to make a connection to the MySQL database with .createPool tells me this error:

**Property 'getConnection' does not exist on type 'Bluebird'. Did you forget to use 'await'?**

I tried it a few months ago and everything went perfectly :/. 
I think that in version 3 of promise-mysql there were some changes.
I'm using typescript and I try to perform a rest API

Use "promise-mysql": "^4.0.4", ES6,

```
`import mysql from 'promise-mysql';

import keys from './keys';

const pool = mysql.createPool(keys.database);

pool.getConnection()
    .then((connection: any) => {
        pool.releaseConnection(connection);
        console.log('DB is connected');
    });
export default pool;`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
import mysql from 'mysql';

import keys from './keys';

const pool = mysql.createPool(keys.database);

pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    connection.release();
    console.log('DB is connected');
})
export default pool;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
`enter code here`**Importa desde 'mysql' proque soporta las librerias de getConnection()**

import mysql from 'mysql';`enter code here`
import keys from './keys';

const pool = mysql.createPool(keys.database);


pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
     if (err) throw err; connection.release(); 
     console.log('DB is connected'); 

});


**Tu contolador quedaria asi:**

import{Request, Response} from 'express';
import pool from '../database';

class GamesController{
    public index(req: Request, res: Response){
        pool.query('DESCRIBE games');
        res.json('games');
    }
}
const gamesController = new GamesController();
export default gamesController;
```

Comment: Can you explain why your answer works? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: so the question says that getConnection doesn't exist on pool. How can he fix it? then the answer is: 'you should do 'pool.getConnection'. But he just said it doesn't exist on pool!

Comment: @RodnalCode pool.query also doesn't exist: Property 'query' does not exist on type 'Bluebird<Pool>'

Answer (score 1):

My solution

```
import mysql from 'promise-mysql';

import keys from './keys';

const pool = mysql.createPool(keys.database);

pool.then((r: any) => r.getConnection().then((connection:any)=>{
    r.releaseConnection(connection);
    console.log('Conexion exitosa.')
}));

export default pool;
```

Comment: Some words explaining your solution would make it more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Install the last version of Promise-MySql:

```
npm i promise-mysql@3.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting until the pool has finished being created:

```
pool.then((r: any) => r.getConnection().then((connection: any) => {
  pool.releaseConnection(connection);
  console.log("DB is connected");
});
```

Comment: and then: Property 'releaseConnection' does not exist on type 'Bluebird<Pool>'

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this version
npm install promise-mysql@3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

you must change the version of promise-mysql to 3.3.1 and that is it.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't downgrade your library version!**

Also you don't need to install another library. It just changed, so you need to make some changes:

```
import mysql, { Pool, PoolConnection } from "promise-mysql";
import keys from "./keys";

const pool = (query: string): Promise<any> => {
  return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    let connection: PoolConnection;
    mysql
      .createPool(keys.database)
      .then((mysqlPool: Pool) => mysqlPool.getConnection())
      .then((conn: PoolConnection) => {
        connection = conn;
        console.log("Connection opened", query);
        return connection.query(query);
      })
      .then((result: any) => {
        console.log("Query executed successfully");
        connection.release();
        console.log("Connection closed");
        resolve(result);
      })
      .catch((error: Error) => {
        console.error("An error occurred:", error);
        if (connection) {
          connection.release();
        }
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};

export default pool;
```

and you use it from your controller like this:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import pool from "../database";

class GamesController {
  index(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const query = "SELECT * FROM games";
    pool(query)
      .then((result) => {
        res.json(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}

export const gamesController = new GamesController();
```